# I want to track visitor visits and change behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, analytics

I want to write a script that tracks visitor visits on my page and do the following things:

behavior 1)If this is the first visit to the site, prompt the user for their first and last names, and provide radio buttons with "red", blue", "yellow", Green"

behavior 2) IF the user presses the submit button but has left one of the name fields empty, tell the user to press their browser's BACK button and enter both names. The user must enter a first name and a last name.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>track visits</title>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
</head>
<body style = "background-color:#f5f5f5;color#080808">


<Main>
<h2>  New Media and Web Design</h2>
<p> Welcome to Media Design it will bring your company &rsquo;s Web preference to the next level.<br> We offer a comprehensive range of services
</p>


</body>
</html>

if(isset($_COOKIE['a']))
{

    $c = $_COOKIE['a'] + 1;

    setcookie("a", $c, time() + 60 * 60 * 24);


    echo "Visit number: " . $_COOKIE['a'];
}
else
{
        setcookie("a", "1", time() + 60 * 60 * 24);
}
If $_COOKIE['a']= 1{

    echo "hello";
}

?>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question here. You've only stated what you plan to do.

Comment: Have you tried to implement this at all? The code provided a) isn't valid, and b) doesn't show anything that looks like you've made a try yourself.

Comment: I wan to know how to add the behaviours that I want the php to execute

Comment: So what have tried yourself? SO is here to help you with coding problems. Not to do your job for you. If you need a point in the right direction: Perhaps it's a good idea to detect a unique user based on IP address and use cookies to differentiate between multiple users behind 1 IP.

Comment: I hope that most of this is for educational purposes or a simple online game. If you are asking all of your visitors to enter their full names you will find that most viewers will just imediately leave your site.

Comment: Your php isn't going to run without an opening `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php. According to the PHP manual cookies are a mechanism for storing data in the remote browser and thus tracking or identifying return users.

So what you can do is every time they log on, check to see if there is a cookie from your website on their computer, if there is none it means it is their first time on the site, if there is one it means they have been on the website before.

How to create a new cookie:

```
<?php 
setcookie("name","value",time()+$time-the-cookie-expires);
$_COOKIE['lg'] = 'ro';
?>
```

how to check if cookie exists:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['lg'])) {}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to his question. It's a point into the right direction, I'll give you that. But therefor it should be a comment and not an answer ;)